# symfony architecture for multi customer application

Tags: symfony

I have a server, lets say www.myserver.com and i want to host a php symfony application for several customers.
For example customer 'abc' and 'xyz' I will have 2 separated database abc and xyz

Now, I want my customers to access like this:

www.myserver.com/abc

www.myserver.com/xyz

I'm a newbie at Symfony, my application works when calling www.myserver.com/abc/app_dev.php  its in development

I have routing problems for the home page, and I dont see how to specify the database, because the parameters.yml files seems to be shared

Thanks for hints

Regards

Comment: You should have a look at the theming bundle like LiipThemeBundle.

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar issue some time ago. What I had to do is to have:

```
/client_1 (Client1 app dir)
/client_2 (Client2 app dir)
...
/web
    /client_1 (Client1 web dir)
    /client_2 (Client2 app dir)
    ...
```

This way, your have separate apps which share the same codebase (`src`) but also have separate logs, config, etc...

But please, reconsider the decision to have this. I learned too late that I should not have done that way. By that time, it was too late to do anything. The reason was that some of the clients requested "special" features which other did not.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes, its my case. Its a Platform, so i want to share the same features accross all clients, so sharing the same codebase (src) is okay for me. but sorry to ask again, i cannot figure out what to change to make it work, im a bit lost with routing. where and how do i specify client1 app dir ?